# #VBA Private Sub Worksheet_Change

Tags: vba

Could any kind soul help me, I have spent a considerable amount of time searching and trying to get these 2 pieces of code to work, but couldn't.

Is there any way I can combine these 2 snippets? They serve two different purposes.

1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Len(Target) = 10 Then
        Range("I" & Target.Row & ":J" & Target.Row & ", K" & Target.Row & ", M" & Target.Row) = "N"
    End If
End Sub
```

2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 12 And Target.Value = "Y" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
    End If
End Sub
```

I am at a loss....

Comment: care to share what isnt working exactly?

Comment: What is your question? Please describe at least what you want to archive with the code. And I don't really understand why it should be hard to make one routine out of it.

Comment: My 1st code works but 2nd code is not working, i have tried numerous ways to combine but to no avail.

Comment: I am new to VBA, sorry if my question was unclear. I understand there cannot be 2 Worksheet_Change in the same procedure, so i tried to combine it into one, however the 2nd code is not picking up anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the code below.
Disable events to stop the Change event firing when you update the values in columns `I:K` & `N`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target

        If .Column = 12 Then
            If .Value = "Y" Then
                .Offset(, 1) = Date
            End If
        ElseIf .Column = 1 Then
            If Len(.Value) = 10 Then
                Cells(.Row, 9).Resize(, 3) = "N" 'Column I:K
                Cells(.Row, 13) = "N" 'Column M
            End If
        End If

    End With

EXIT_PROC:

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 13 'Type mismatch.
            Resume EXIT_PROC
        Case Else 'Any unhandled errors.
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error in " & ThisWorkbook.Name
            Resume EXIT_PROC
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Edit after accepted:**
I've added an error handler to the code at the suggestion of @MathieuGuindon.  After dealing with the error the code jumps back to the `EXIT_PROC` label so there's only a single exit point to the procedure.

Comment: Excellent. Only thing missing is some error-handling, so that if `.Value` contains an error value, when e.g. `If .Value = "Y" Then` throws a *type mismatch* error and execution exits abruptly, leaving `Application.EnableEvents` toggled off.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as a combined method:

You need do disable alerts when making changes while you have a worksheet_change event loaded on a macro, else you may find yourself in a infinite loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Or Target.Column <> 12 Then Exit Sub

    If Len(Target) = 10 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range(Cells(Target.Row, "I"), Cells(Target.Row, "K")) = "N"
            Range("M" & Target.Row) = "N"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Target.Column = 12 And Target.Value = "Y" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted, but the infinite loop would be caused by `Application.EnableEvents` being toggled on and `Worksheet_Change` re-entering when a cell is modified. Disabling alerts won't fix that ;-)

Comment: AGH brain lag on my part. thats what I meant* updating

Comment: Thank you both, much appreciated!