# Today function gets overwritten by the date itself

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula in the M1 cell:

```
=IF(K19="N","",IF(K19="Y",TODAY()))
```

When I input Y in K1, K1 displays the date but the formula in M1 gets overwritten by the date itself. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Sounds like there is a piece of code running in that workbook. What you are describing is not something the formula is able to do.

Comment: As @Jerry said.  Does your workbook have an `xlsm` extension indicating it has some code?  Press `Alt+F11` to bring up the Visual Basic Editor.  Press `Ctrl+R` in this window to bring up the `Project Explorer` - find your file listed and look in the `ThisWorkbook` and `Sheet1(Your Sheet Name)` - may differ slightly depending on which sheet you're having problems with  `- Excel objects.  Is there a code in either of those two?

Comment: Is this in the same sheet as the code you were asking about yesterday?  [Private Sub Worksheet_Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067171/vba-private-sub-worksheet-change).  That code fires whenever a change is made on the sheet and part of it does overwrite values in column M (if the length of the value in column A of that row is = 10).

Comment: Hi Darren Bartrup-Cook! Didn't come across my mind it is conflicting with the VBA code, I understand now! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the SWITCH function instead of a nested IF function (the SWITCH function only works in Excel 2016).

`=SWITCH(K19, "N", "", "Y", TODAY(), [optional default value])`

This may not fix your issue. As some of the comments above mentioned, you might have some macros running in the background that override what you're doing.